# Debian Wheezy PHP downgrading/upgrading questions

Tags: php, debian, configuration, debian-wheezy, downgrade

Hello serverfault guys,

I have a Debian Wheezy (7.2) server and it came with PHP 5.4 by default, I was installing Ensignia Mail which is a PHP 5.3 only application and it gave me a lot of errors, so I tried to downgrade the PHP version to 5.3 by adding the squeeze sources on /etc/apt/sources.list and reinstalling the package, more specifficaly, I've followed this tutorial: http://blog.wpkg.org/2013/06/20/downgrading-to-php-5-3-on-debian-wheezy-7-0/

And then the application worked just fine, but after, I removed the sources from Debian Squeeze and installed PHP 5.4 again. But the application continued working instead of hanging as it did before.

The developer of the application says that the app is incompatible with PHP 5.4, maybe I have some configuration files of PHP 5.3 on my PHP 5.4 installation? how do I check this?

English is not my main language so please, bear with me!

Comment: `phpinfo();` to check what version you are using.

Comment: I am running PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u5, I've compared my php.ini with a fresh installed PHP 5.4 installation and they are the same, I don't know how I made the app work just by downgrading and upgrading again, it is just the php.ini that php checks or does it have any other file?

Comment: Did you `apt-get purge php5-*` before pinning and installing again?

Answer (score 0):

`phpinfo()` will give you the `php.ini` path.

You also can do:

```
sudo find /etc/* -name php.ini
```

and check the other configuration files.

If you are running with nginx installation you may look at: `fpm/php.ini`.